# Check cell value before post data to server

Tags: validation, jqgrid, inline-editing

I'm having a problem checking cell value after an inline edit and before save data. Part of my ColModel is (without any unnesessary code):

```
{name:'event_start_date',index:'event_start_date',width:75,align:'center',editable:true,edittype:'text',editoptions:{size:'10',maxlength:'10',
      dataInit:function(el){
        $(el).mask('9999-99-99');
        $(el).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
          beforeShow: function(input, instance){instance.dpDiv.css({marginTop: '1px'});}})
      }}
    },
    {name:'event_start_time',index:'event_start_time',width:70,align:'center',editable:true,edittype:'text',editoptions:{size:'8',maxlength:'8',
      dataInit:function(el){$(el).mask('99:99:99');}}
    },
    {name:'event_end_date',index:'event_end_date',width:75,align:'center',editable:true,edittype:'text',editoptions:{size:'10',maxlength:'10',
      dataInit:function(el){
        $(el).mask('9999-99-99');
        $(el).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
          beforeShow: function(input, instance){instance.dpDiv.css({marginTop: '1 px'});}})
      }}
    },
    {name:'event_end_time',index:'event_end_time',width:70,align:'center',editable:true,edittype:'text',editoptions:{size:'8',maxlength:'8',
      dataInit:function(el){$(el).mask('99:99:99');}}
    },
    {name:'event_dur_calc',index:'event_dur_calc',width:90,align:'center',editable:false,edittype:'text',sorttype:'date',editoptions:{size:'10',maxlength:'10'}
    }
```

I'm using double click to get inline edit mode. After user make some changes into date/time fields, new value calculated for cell "event_dur_calc":

```
$('#'+rowId+'_event_start_date').focusout(function(){recalc_dur(rowId);});
$('#'+rowId+'_event_start_time').focusout(function(){recalc_dur(rowId);});
$('#'+rowId+'_event_end_date').focusout(function(){recalc_dur(rowId);});
$('#'+rowId+'_event_endt_time').focusout(function(){recalc_dur(rowId);});
```

Functions fo calculating new time:

```
function mktime(){
  var i = 0, d = new Date(), argv = arguments, argc = argv.length;
  var dateManip = {
    0: function(tt){ return d.setHours(tt); },
    1: function(tt){ return d.setMinutes(tt); },
    2: function(tt){ return d.setSeconds(tt); },
    3: function(tt){ return d.setMonth(parseInt(tt)-1); },
    4: function(tt){ return d.setDate(tt); },
    5: function(tt){ return d.setYear(tt); }
  };
  for( i = 0; i < argc; i++ ){
    if(argv[i] && isNaN(argv[i])){
      return false;
    } else if(argv[i]){
      if(!dateManip[i](argv[i])){
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return Math.floor(d.getTime()/1000);
}; 

function recalc_dur(rowId){
  var event_start_date_txt = $('#'+rowId+'_event_start_date').val();
  var event_start_time_txt = $('#'+rowId+'_event_start_time').val();
  var event_end_date_txt = $('#'+rowId+'_event_end_date').val();
  var event_end_time_txt = $('#'+rowId+'_event_end_time').val();

  if (event_end_date_txt=='0000-00-00'){
    $('#'+rowId+'_event_dur_calc').val('0000:00:00');
  }else{
    var start_d_pices = event_start_date_txt.split('-');
    var start_t_pices = event_start_time_txt.split(':');
    var end_d_pices = event_end_date_txt.split('-');
    var end_t_pices = event_end_time_txt.split(':');
    var start_time = mktime(start_t_pices[0], start_t_pices[1], start_t_pices[2], start_d_pices[1], start_d_pices[2], start_d_pices[0]);
    var end_time = mktime(end_t_pices[0], end_t_pices[1], end_t_pices[2], end_d_pices[1], end_d_pices[2], end_d_pices[0]);
    var delta = end_time-start_time;
    var secs = delta % 60;
    delta = (delta - secs) / 60;
    if (secs.toString().length==1) var new_dur = ':0'+secs; else var new_dur = ':'+secs;
    var mins = delta % 60;
    delta = (delta - mins) / 60;
    if (mins.toString().length==1) new_dur = ':0'+mins+new_dur; else new_dur = ':'+mins+new_dur;
    var hours = delta;
    if (hours.toString().length==1){new_dur = '000'+hours+new_dur;
    }else if (hours.toString().length==2){new_dur = '00'+hours+new_dur;
    }else if (hours.toString().length==3){new_dur = '0'+hours+new_dur;
    }else new_dur = hours+new_dur;
    $('tr[id=\"'+rowId+'\"] > td[aria-describedby=\"dfr_event_dur_calc\"]').html(new_dur);
  }
}
```

If the new calculating time will be below zero (when start date/time is greater than end date/time), modal window with alert message is appers and data can't be saved and posted on server.

Is there any event in inline edit mode that fires before posting data, that I can use to check new calculating value to prevent incorrect data will be saved?

Answer (score 0):

The current code of jqGrid on [github](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid) contains `beforeSaveRow` callback function which will be called before saving. The changes was made *after* publishing of jqGrid 4.5.2, but the feature will be exist in the next version (>4.5.2) of jqGrid. So if you don't want use developer sources from github you can use the standard validation way: usage [editrules](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editrules) with `custom: true` and [custom_func](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#custom_checking_example) which do the validation.